# Submitting redux-form form like a normal HTML form if validation passes, touching all fields if not

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers, redux-form

I'm trying to build a form that will submit like any other HTML form if redux-form validation passes. If validation fails, I want it to touch all the fields and prevent submission.

So I need to either: write my own onSubmit function that will touch the fields if validation fails. Which I'm trying:

This implementation:

```
handleSubmit (event) {
  const {touch, fields} = this.props
  if (!allValid(fields)) {
    event.preventDefault()
    touch(...fields)
  }
}
```

Yields this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` out of the call to `touch`. I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down where exactly this error is occurring in the implementation of `touch`, but it's definitely the call to `touch` that's causing it.

Using the built-in handleSubmit will get the touching behavior right if validation fails, but I can't figure out how to get it to submit the form like a normal HTML form if validation passes as well without doing something hacky like this:

```
handleSubmit (event) {
  const {touch, fields} = this.props
  if (!allValid(fields)) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.handleSubmit(() => {})()
  }
}
```

Which does work, but seems like a bad way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `touch` is expecting an array of strings not an array of objects. So you're probably wanting `touch(...Object.keys(fields))`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Where would I have found this myself? I tried looking through the docs, but I wasn't able to find anything specifically about the action itself.

Comment: The doc line is "touch(...field:string) : Function" -- Admittedly terse and somewhat misleading since elsewhere on the page "fields" is an object.  An example would probably help a lot as well.